# htaccess using GET to use parameters to rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The actual link = https://www.website.com/lsearch.jhtm?keywords=test&promocode=joe-shmoe&srTc=joe-shmoe

The link I want to show = 
https://www.website.com/joe-shmoe/lsearch.jhtm?keywords=test

I've tried some of these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/lsearch$ /lsearch.jhtm?promocode=$1&srTc=$1 [QSA]
&
RewriteRule ^(.*)/lsearch$ lsearch.jhtm?promocode=$1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)/(.*)\.html$ category.jhtm?cid=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^lsearch/$ lsearch.jhtm [QSA]
#RewriteRule ^lsearch$ search
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/lsearch$ /lsearch.jhtm?promocode=$1&srTc=$1 [QSA]


#RewriteRule ^(.[^/lsearch]*)$ lsearch.jhtm?promocode=$1&srTc=$1 [QSA]
#RewriteRule ^lsearch$ /lsearch.jhtm?keywords=$1 [QSA]
#RewriteRule ^lsearch\.jhtm$ /lsearch.jhtm?keywords=$1 [QSA]
```

EDIT: I've tried some of these rules. Not all these rules at the same time.

Comment: HTTP Status 404 ---
Issue is this: WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/amy-knox/lsearch.jhtm] in DispatcherServlet with name ‘webjaguar’ ---

Looks like the url isn’t being properly converted by the .htacces

Comment: I just added "keywords=test" as the first parameter. That was missing

Comment: No, I added that into "I'm trying to get" -- My rewrite rules are not working. Do you know what would work for what I'm doing?

Comment: Does `https://www.website.com/joe-shmoe/lsearch.jhtm?keywords=test` work from your browser? How is Apache sending rewritten URLs to your Spring app?

Comment: I’m pretty sure requests come hit apache and then are served to tomcat and the application.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try Below Rewrite Rule in your .htaccess file -

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/lsearch/$ lsearch.jhtm?promocode=$1&srTc=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^lsearch/$ lsearch.jhtm [QSA]
```

Comment: I don't see what you changed from my own answer.